# Java invokes String.valueOf(char[] data) instead of String.valueOf(int i) for Integer parameter and throw ClassCastException

Tags: java, string, classcastexception

I have a problem with invoking String.valueOf method. As argument I passed generic method which returns Integer type. And then exception is thrown because program try to cast that returned Integer to char[] to invoke String.valueOf method. As I know String has overloaded valueOf() method and one of them can take Integer parameter.

Below is screenshot from Eclipse expression evaluation which shows situation.

[image: Evaluated expression]

This line throws ClassCastException

```
String quality = String.valueOf(model.get(property));
```

This is what model.get(property) invokes:

```
public <X> X get(String property) {
        X value = null;
        try {
            if (allowNestedValues && NestedModelUtil.isNestedProperty(property)) {
                return (X) NestedModelUtil.getNestedValue(this, property);
            }
            if (map != null) {
                Object objValue = map.get(property);
                if (objValue != null)
                    value = (X) objValue;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return map == null ? null : value;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I added this condition and compiler goes inside the if statement

```
if(model.get(property) instanceof Integer)
{
    quality = String.valueOf(model.get(property));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Stop describing your code, **show** your code. And post the stacktrace.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54292561/edit) and add a [mcve] of code which reproduces this exception?

Comment: How do you expect the Java compiler to correctly infer which `String.valueOf` variant to use?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel then how Java compiler know that it is Integer instance ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski That is a runtime exception... while apparently it was compiled to invoke `String.valueOf(char[])` (which might be an Eclipse specific problem BTW as it uses its own compiler).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok Mark now I understand what do you mean

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But one more question. Why does it compile to valueOf(char[]) ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski Could have to do with how to compiler attempts to select the most specific type. I'm not sure if that is standard Java behavior or specific to the Eclipse Java compiler.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I will try to find some information about it. Thank you for your explanation

Comment: `valueOf` has overloads for `Object`, `char[]` and various primitive types. `char[]` is the "most specific" one and is therefore chosen (presumably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is the compiler supposed to infer the correct `X` the way you call it?

Split it into

```
YourType qualityRaw = model.get(property);
String quality = String.valueOf(qualityRaw);
```

Comment: Doing `String.valueOf(model.<YourType>get(property)` might also work.

Comment: Why instanceof Integer returns true ?

Comment: Check attached screenshot where instanceof is evaluated and value is true

Comment: @RafałSokalski You are confusing runtime types with compile time inferred types. Method resolution is done at compile time, and here that inferrence turns out to be wrong which results in a runtime class cast exception.

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should try Integer.toString method if you know that your return type is of Integer type.